# AttributeError: module 'OpenSSL.SSL' has no attribute 'TLS_METHOD'

Tags: scrapy-settings

When trying to import scrapy in my Jupyter Notebooks via Anaconda (Windows), I get this error, which I haven´t been able to solve. I'm working with Python 3.

What I did till now:

pip install Scrapy
pip install pyopenssl
import scrapy

and I get the following error:

[TLS METHOD ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYN1r.png)

Tks for your help.
Gisselle

Answer (score 0):

I Have installed latest version of  cryptography which worked for me . You can try it

```
pip install cryptography
```